# How to create an automatic table of contents in word using Visual Basic 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, ms-word

I am trying to create an 'Assignment Template creator'. It's basically for college but it't not an assignment so no one will get in trouble here. But I managed to find the amazing code example to create a word document using Visual Basic 2010 or the Visual Basic language. I've modified it just a bit so that it can take the information from the text boxes and put them in the text boxes. All that works and creating a new page works.

But how can I create a Table of Contents (TOC) using the same code listed below:

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
```

Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim oWord As Word.Application
    Dim oDoc As Word.Document
    Dim oTable As Word.Table
    Dim oPara1 As Word.Paragraph, oPara2 As Word.Paragraph
    Dim oPara3 As Word.Paragraph, oPara4 As Word.Paragraph
    Dim oRng As Word.Range
    Dim oShape As Word.InlineShape
    Dim oChart As Object
    Dim Pos As Double
    Dim what As Object = Word.WdGoToItem.wdGoToLine
    Dim which As Object = Word.WdGoToDirection.wdGoToLast
    Const wdPageBreak = 1


    'Start Word and open the document template.'
    oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    oWord.Visible = True
    oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add

    'Insert a paragraph at the beginning of the document.'
    oDoc.Range.Font.Size = "16"
    oPara1 = oDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add
    oPara1.Range.Text = stuName.Text
    oPara1.Range.InsertParagraphAfter()

    'Insert a paragraph at the beginning of the document.'
    oPara1 = oDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add
    oPara1.Range.Text = centNo.Text
    oPara1.Range.InsertParagraphAfter()

    'Insert a paragraph at the beginning of the document.'
    oPara1 = oDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add
    oPara1.Range.Text = units.Text
    oPara1.Range.InsertParagraphAfter()

    'Insert a paragraph at the beginning of the document.'
    oPara1 = oDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add
    oPara1.Range.Text = tutor.Text
    oPara1.Range.InsertParagraphAfter()

    'Insert a paragraph at the beginning of the document.'
    oPara1 = oDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add
    oPara1.Range.Text = dueDate.Text
    oPara1.Range.InsertParagraphAfter()

    'Insert a new page'
    oWord.Selection.GoTo(what, which, Nothing, Nothing)
    Dim objSelection = oWord.Selection
    objSelection.InsertBreak(wdPageBreak)

    'Insert a table of contents'

    With oDoc
        .TablesOfContents.Add(Range:=oWord.Selection.Range, _
                   RightAlignPageNumbers:=True, _
                   UseHeadingStyles:=True, _
                   IncludePageNumbers:=True, _
                   AddedStyles:="Automatic Table 1", _
                   UseHyperlinks:=False, _
                   HidePageNumbersInWeb:=True, _
                   UseOutlineLevels:=True)
        .TablesOfContents(1).Range.Font.Name = "Arial Narrow"
        .TablesOfContents(1).Range.Font.Size = 11
        .TablesOfContents(1).TabLeader = Word.WdTabLeader.wdTabLeaderDots
        .TablesOfContents.Format = Word.WdTocFormat.wdTOCTemplate
    End With

    'Insert another blank page'



    'All done. Close this form.

    Me.Close()

End Sub
```

End Class

You can see there is already a table of contents code in there, but it's not the one I want. I want it to use one of words templates. The Automatic one!

You can see it's sort of basic and I got it from here: [How to automate Word from Visual Basic .NET to create a new document](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/316383)

All of it works, but I want to create the 'Automatic Table of contents 1' Template in word. I don't need it to update all the time, I just want it to add one and then the program will close.

Sorry it's such a long question and if you don't understand I will reply back when I can. But if anyone can help. It would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Dan

Comment: A tip for this kind of thing: Record the steps for creating the TOC in a macro. This will tell you the syntax for inserting the kind of TOC you want. Use this as the basis for adjusting the code you have to create that kind of TOC. Since you're using VB.NET it should be reasonably straight-forward.

Comment: I used the macros, but it didn't really help. But thanks anyway

Comment: HOW did it not help?

Comment: `Application.Templates( _
        "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Document Building Blocks\1033\16\Built-In Building Blocks.dotx" _
        ).BuildingBlockEntries("Automatic Table 1").Insert Where:=Selection.Range _
        , RichText:=True` **This didn't really help me**

Comment: Thank you for the additional info.

Answer (score 0):

A Table of Contents is managed in Word using a TOC field code. Press Alt+F9 to toggle on the field code display. You need to recreate this field code.

There are two basic ways to go about it:

1. Insert the field code. This is less "intuitive", but you can essentially build it from exactly what you see in the document field code.
2. Use the Document.TablesOfContents.Add method. This is more intuitive, on the surface, but requires you to understand exactly what commands the field code and its switches (the backslash + additional info) do.

If you want to know, you can look up the information on the TOC field and its switches (https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Field-codes-TOC-Table-of-Contents-field-1f538bc4-60e6-4854-9f64-67754d78d05c?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US). But quicker and easier for you would be to copy what's between the { field brackets } and paste that into your code. (Note: be careful to NOT select the { brackets }!)

```
'Insert TOC field at beginning of document
Dim rngDocStart as Word.Range
Set rngDocStart = ActiveDocument.Content
rngDocStart.Collapse
rngDocStart.Fields.Add Range:=rngDocStart, _
  Type:=wdFieldEmpty, _
  Text:="the text you copy from the field code", _
  PreserveFormatting:=False
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm really not helping both of us here. But I copied the code and I assume I'm doing something wrong because this is what I typed: `Dim rngDocStart As Word.Range
        rngDocStart = oDoc.Content
        rngDocStart.Collapse()
        rngDocStart.Fields.Add(Range:=rngDocStart, _
          Type:="Automatic Table 1", _
          Text:="TOC \o 1-3 \h \z \u", _
          PreserveFormatting:=False)`  **When I run it I get an error code of** `Type mismatch. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020005 (DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH))`

Comment: Use the same Type as in my code sample. The only thing you change is what's assigned to Text:= and that looks exactly right in what you show in the Comment.

Comment: I haven't tried it yet because I don't have Office installed at the minute due to losing hard drive space. When I get it back eventually I will let you know. And thanks for asking :)